# Tab fragment -Tab changes with button action in side the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am working on ViewPager with TabsPagerAdapter, i have successfully created two tabs like a and b. my button is placed in  a tab if i click on button, it has to  b tab.

Main activity is -

```
private ViewPager viewPager;
private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
private ActionBar actionBar;
// Tab titles
private String[] tabs = { "Top Rated", "Games" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    /**
     * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
     * */
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            // on changing the page
            // make respected tab selected
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // on tab selected
    // show respected fragment view
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
}}
```

Tabpageadaper is -

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Top Rated fragment activity
        return new TopRatedFragment();
    case 1:
        // Games fragment activity
        return new GamesFragment();
    case 2:
        // Movies fragment activity
        return new MoviesFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

My button is placed at Top Rated tab as shown below -

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {
private int currentPage;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
    Button b1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

}

When i click on above button it has to open games tab.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To change `Tab/Fragment` you can use `viewPager.setCurrentItem()` method.

1. Write a `public` method in your `MainActivity.java` like below:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       ................
       ........................
   }

   public void selectTab(int position) {
       viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
   }
   ```
2. Use `selectTab()` method from your `TopRatedFragment.java` to select `GamesFragment`.

   ```
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
       Button b1=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               ((MainActivity)getActivity()).selectTab(1); // 1 for GamesFragment
           }
       });

       return rootView;
   }
   ```

Comment: if i created viewpager in fragment then? @ferdous

Answer (score 1):

You can use `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);` to select `viewPager` target page

so put this method in your `Activity`

```
public void chooseTab(int position){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
}
```

and then you can call it from any fragment like this

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).chooseTab(0)
```

just pass the target tab position

Answer (score 0):

In your MainActivity add a public method -

```
public void selectFragment(int position){
     viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);
     // true is to animate the transaction
}
```

then in you `TopRatedFragment b1.setOnClickListener` set this code below -

```
((MainActivity)getActivity()).selectFragment(1); //1 is second position
```